# Class in secondary dex file not found after MultiDex.install

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-multidex

I have setup multiDex and multiDex Install Log

```
08-27 01:38:38.091  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
08-27 01:38:38.091  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ install
08-27 01:38:38.093  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.douban.frodo-2.apk, false)
08-27 01:38:38.100  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ Detected that extraction must be performed.
08-27 01:38:38.101  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ Trying to delete old file /data/data/com.douban.frodo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.douban.frodo-1.apk.classes2.dex of size 2096960
08-27 01:38:38.106  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ Deleted old file /data/data/com.douban.frodo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.douban.frodo-1.apk.classes2.dex
08-27 01:38:38.106  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ Trying to delete old file /data/data/com.douban.frodo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.douban.frodo-1.apk.classes2.zip of size 820574
08-27 01:38:38.111  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ Deleted old file /data/data/com.douban.frodo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.douban.frodo-1.apk.classes2.zip
08-27 01:38:38.187  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ Extraction is needed for file /data/data/com.douban.frodo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.douban.frodo-2.apk.classes2.zip
08-27 01:38:38.188  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ Extracting /data/data/com.douban.frodo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.douban.frodo-2.apk.classes-820936325.zip
08-27 01:38:38.798  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ Renaming to /data/data/com.douban.frodo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.douban.frodo-2.apk.classes2.zip
08-27 01:38:38.798  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ Extraction success - length /data/data/com.douban.frodo/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.douban.frodo-2.apk.classes2.zip: 820574
08-27 01:38:38.799  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ load found 1 secondary dex files
08-27 01:38:39.604  16212-16212/com.douban.frodo I/MultiDex﹕ install done
```

BUT

Class not found when application initialize.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.douban.push.PushClient$Helper
        at com.douban.frodo.FrodoApplication.onCreate(FrodoApplication.java:77)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4596)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1407)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:835)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And I found that **PushClient** is in the secondary dex file with apktool

I don't understand why?

Comment: when i do not use these code, the problem is not occured .
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
//        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
       dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=$rootDir/main_dex_list.txt".toString()
    }
}

Comment: You don't need to manually add additional parameters to your dex task. Instead, use the plugin support by specifying "multiDexEnabled = true". For more info see here: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle